# Scala Specs2 throws error "Could not create an instance of Proxies" on Api call

Tags: scala, unit-testing, specs2

I am trying to write **unit tests** in **Scala** using **specs2**. I want to test a third-party api (Bluemix watson) that is written inside my **send()** function.

```
class BMProxy() extends BaseProxy()
{
    override def send(data:JsValue):JsValue =
    {
        val id = "--123---"
        val workspaceid = "---xyz---"
        val username = "---username---"
        val password = "---password---"
        val bluemixURL = s"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/$id/message?version=2016-07-11"
       Logger.info(s"data: $data")

        val req = WS.url(bluemixURL).
          withAuth(username, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC).
          withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").
          post(data.toString).
          map {
            response => {
              val rawbody = response.body
              val responsecode = response.status
              val responsetext = response.statusText
              Json.parse(rawbody)
              }
          }
         Await.result(req, 5 seconds)
    }   
}
```

and below is the **unit test method** of the above method:

```
class Proxies extends Specification {
"Chatscript proxy" should {
    "gives response" in {
      val data = Json.parse("""{"input":{"text":"Hey"},"context":{"conversation_id":"234234234" } }""")
      val response = new BMProxy().send(data)
      println("---", response)
      Json.stringify(response) must contain ("response")
    }
  }
}
```

but it throws ***error*** -

```
[error] Could not create an instance of Proxies
[error]   caused by java.lang.Exception: Could not instantiate class Proxies: null
[error]
```

Comment: This generally means that you are instantiating vals in the body of your Specification class. You should "protect" those values by making them lazy vals.

Comment: @Eric: When I made val to "lazy vals", it gives error "There is no started Application".

Comment: I am sorry but it is hard to debug this kind of problem without having the whole code. But using lazy vals is definitely my recommendation.